# ORA-01017: invalid username/password thrown by Flyway on Jenkins

Tags: oracle, jenkins, flyway

My PC is currently running an Oracle 19c on my localhost. I am trying to invoke Flyway from Jenkins, which is also running on my local PC. I have already supplied the correct username and password in the JDBC URL in the "Invoke Flyway" build step of Jenkins as shown in the picture below.

[image]

However, when I try to build the job, the Jenkins job failed with the following error:

> Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:oracle:thin:username/********@//localhost:1521/orclpdb) for user 'null': ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

[image]

I am able to run the same command in the command prompt and obtain the result without the logon denied error:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by adding the credential to Jenkin  and applying it in the "Invoke Flyway" build step instead of passing them along with the Database URL.

[image]